# I wonder if I need to send a check to the value in the reCAPTCHA

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

I have applied with reCAPTCHA as follows: angularJS

```
<div class="captcha-box">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<site-key>" g-recaptcha-response="gRecaptchaResponse" control="captchaControl"></div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

But I am confused what to do in the certified value reCAPTCHA To give handled through a directive.

How can that will send the results of the field in the result reCAPTCHA?